# Two-column text, landscape pages

Tags: two-column, landscape

I wish to create a pdf-file out of a tex-file, so that the text is printed in two columns, and pages are to have the landspace orientation. The standard way to do this, as I see on the Net, is to say

```
\documentclass[landscape,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}
```

However on my system (Win 7, MiKTeX 2.8) it produces a pdf-file with the "portrait" pages. What's the reason of that?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: If you indent a line by 4 spaces, then it's marked as a code sample.

Comment: Thanks! Indenting = blockquoting, that's a nice feature.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add `\usepackage{geometry}` and it should work. The options from the article class get handed to geometry, which then sets it up nicely.

Alternatively, pass the options to it directly: `\usepackage[landscape,twocolumn]{geometry}`

Comment: Worked as a charm, thank you very much indeed.

Comment: Note that the title will look different whether the options are passed directly to `geometry` or passed to the class with `geometry`.